# If Condition combined with OR

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, if-statement

I have the following example:

```
data = {'model': ['Lisa', 'Lisa 2', 'Macintosh 128K', 'Macintosh 512K'],
        'launched': [1983,1984,1984,1984],
        'discontinued': [1986, 1985, 1984, 1986]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['model', 'launched', 'discontinued'])

def set_row(row):
    if ((row["model"] == "Lisa")):
        return "hello"
    else:
        return "null"

df['new Column'] = df.apply(set_row, axis=1)
```

The example gives me a table output with a new column containing "hello" and "null".

```
            model  launched  discontinued new Column
0            Lisa      1983          1986      hello
1          Lisa 2      1984          1985       null
2  Macintosh 128K      1984          1984       null
3  Macintosh 512K      1984          1986       null
```

Now I want to enhance the if condition and add another condition similar saying:

if [column model equal "Lisa"] OR [column model contains the string "Mac"] return "hello" in new column otherwise return "null". How can I do that?

I tried:

```
def set_row(row):  
    if ( (row["model"] == "Lisa") | df["model"].str.contains("Mac") ):
        return "hello"
    else:
        return "null"
```

I get an error saying

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is best dont use `apply`, because loop under the hood. Better is   [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = (df["model"] == "Lisa") | df["model"].str.contains("Mac")
df['new Column'] = np.where(mask, "hello", 'null')
```

Or:

```
df['new Column'] = 'null'
df.loc[mask, 'new Column'] = "hello"
```

---

```
print (df)
            model  launched  discontinued new Column
0            Lisa      1983          1986      hello
1          Lisa 2      1984          1985       null
2  Macintosh 128K      1984          1984      hello
3  Macintosh 512K      1984          1986      hello
```

EDIT:

```
def set_row(row):  
    if (row["model"] == "Lisa") or ("Mac" in row["model"]):
        return "hello"
    else:
        return "null"
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael.   How can we do the same thing by keeping the same structure (i.e., by keeping the structure of the function set row)?

Comment: Many Thanks for your help

Comment: just accepted your answer. I completely get what you said about "apply" it is a slow and i am considering using numpy.where as suggested. Would numpy.where work if we had a nested if statement?

Comment: @SBad - better for nested `np.where` is use [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)